# Cursor Lag / Stutter & Media Blacked Out

Tags: display

Wondering if anyone has a solution to the **HDCP** issues with external monitors. I'm fairly desperate for a solution.

I have a 2019 MBP 16, and I’m having cursor lag/stuttering, and media is blacked out on my new LG 4K monitor. Seems to be very, very common and yet I haven't found a solution anywhere.

Things I’ve tried:

- Reset smc and pram.
- All different cables (currently using usb-c to DP).
- All different resolutions and refresh rates.
- The “detect displays” trick.
- Safe mode (*no problem in safe mode*).
- Toggling the auto graphics switching.
- Disconnecting all other usb peripherals, and tried every port.
- Resetting everything on the monitor.
- Downloaded LG's OnScreen Control, and Screen Manager; neither has any firmware update available or solution

Weird things:

- Worked fine for about 2 hours after first hook up.
- Works fine for about 1 minute after turning the monitor off and on.
- Older monitors work great.

I’m working on a graduation project from a programming boot camp, so reinstalling OS or upgrading to Big Sur is a little too risky right now, plus I’ve read it actually gets worse with Big Sur.

I spend 12hrs a day working on this laptop, so if anyone has any input, I would be **very grateful**. It sounds like a common problem, and I find it hard to believe people are living with the mouse lag day to day.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How is the monitor connected to the machine, USB-C or HDMI? I and others are having an issue with cursor hangs with USB-C connections, sometimes to monitors sometimes to hubs. I would try using an HDMI cable, or honestly vice-versa, and seeing if that helps.